# Attaching UIGestureRecognizers to encapsulated UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have an odd issue with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` whereby I always end up with a crash or exception thrown (unrecognised selector) when its action is to be invoked. I have used gesture recognisers before, but this time I am attaching it to a `UIView` which is a property of an `NSObject` (and I am using the object's methods to construct the view). The following is a minimal example of what I am doing:

**MyObject.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *aView;
- (void)createViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```

**MyObject.m:**

```
@interface MyObject ()
- (void)tapped:(id)sender; // Non-specific id type for brevity
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void)tapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
}

- (void)createViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    _aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.aView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(tapped:)];

    [self.aView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    [obj createViewWithFrame:self.view.frame]; // Excuse poor frame - example only

    [self.view addSubview:obj.aView];
}
```

Then, when I tap on the view, the application crashes around here:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x10e008c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x10e0090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x10e0094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x10e0096:  je     0x10e00e8                 ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x10e0098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x10e009a:  pushl  %edi
0x10e009b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi ; Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x9)
0x10e009e:  pushl  %esi
0x10e009f:  movl   (%edi), %esi
0x10e00a1:  movl   %ecx, %edx
```

The exact crash-point varies, and I occasionally receive an invalid selector error. The `NSLog`, naturally, never happens. I have used gesture recognisers before (successfully), which leads me to believe the problem is in my setup/design. Can anyone explain why the gesture recognizer won't work properly in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of the MyObject, Declare the variable globally,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MyObject *obj;
```

in Your viewDidAppear, init and add the view

```
self.obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[self.obj createViewWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
[self.view addSubview:self.obj.aView];
```

That's it.

### Now it is working !!

What was the problem ?, *the scope of the MyObject *obj ends with the viewDidAppear method.
When a tap is recognized, It is looking for the object to fire the method given. But the object is not there.*

Comment: Ah thank you! Can I ask though: It is my understanding that `aView` would retain its gesture recogniser and the view controller's `self.view` would retain its subviews (including `aView`). How is it that `aView` is freed when `obj` is freed? Doesn't `aView` still have objects which `strong`ly retain it?

Comment: you are correct, Your understanding is correct about those views. But the problem here is not with views. Problem is with the view controller. Just check, you have given thrn action:@selector(tapped:) for your gesture. Whenever a tap is received, the gesture finds the tapped: method which is in the obj. If you does not retain the obj then it crashes.